# what the schema of reading big xml data using "Memory Mapped Files"?

Tags: c++, xml, bigdata

i have a big xml file( osm map data file to parse).  the initial code to process is like this:

```
FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");
size_t BUF_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
char* buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
string contents;
while (!feof(file))
{
    int ret = fread(buf, BUF_SIZE, 1, file);
    assert(ret != -1);
    contents.append(buf);
}

size_t pos = 0;
while (true)
{
    pos = contents.find('<', pos);
    if (pos == string::npos) break;

    // Case: found new node.
    if (contents.substr(pos, 5) == "<node")
    {
      do something;
    }

    // Case: found new way.
    else if (contents.substr(pos, 4) == "<way")
    {
       do something;
    }
}
```

then here people tell me i should use memory mapping file to process those "big data file",
detail is here:
[how to read to huge file into buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215946/how-to-read-to-huge-file-into-buffer),

i mean when it is a fixed size and not very large, may i could load one time into memory and append the content to a string object, then i could apply find(), method and other string method to extract the node content of a xml file. ( the code in the beginning of my question use this method and i test that will produce right result). Then if the file is very large, how apply those methods (not using xml library such as libxml)?

in one word, for small xml file, i could load the whole content to a std::string and apply the find(), substr() operation and got wanted information in the xml file. when the xml file is very large, when i need use the memory mapping file to cope with.  then could append the whole content to a std::string, how could i parse the file not using exsit xml library?

hope i have clearly express my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Whether you allocate a buffer (for which you should use vector<char>, not new char[], btw) or memory-map the file is completely irrelevant to parsing that file. Or is there a connection I'm missing? Anyhow, the structure of XML is not in any way based on lines, so if you think about lines when parsing XML you are already on the wrong path. For a large file, I'd use a dedicated XML parser, probably one with a SAX interface.

Comment: You picked the wrong answer on that previous question.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [SAX parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) ? Quote from the article: *Thus, the minimum memory required for a SAX parser is proportional to the maximum depth of the XML file [...]*

Comment: i am not mean that i read the xml file line by line. i mean when it is a fixed size and not very large, may i could load one time into memory and append the content to a string object, then i could apply find(), method and other string method to extract the node content of a xml file. Then if the file is very large, how apply those methods (not using xml library such as libxml)?

Comment: I am sure I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using std::string members to get the data you need, you're almost certainly not parsing the XML in the traditional sense of parsing XML.  (That is, you're very probably not making any use of XML's hierarchical structure.  Although you are extracting data from XML, "parsing XML" means something much more specific to most people.)

That said, the C equivalents of the `std::string` members you seem to be OK with, such as `memcmp` and the GNU extension `memmem`, just take pointers and lengths.  Read their documentation and use them in place of their `std:;string`-member equivalents.